# Cant set wrapping of text till right margin line android studio

Tags: android-studio

I tried to set it in the settings as default as well as for the project Iam working on.

[image: in settings]

That only set the line width but the code still exceeds it.I also checked **Ensure  right margin is not exceeded** for the language I am working on java

[image: for the java language]

That also didn't change anything ,I did it as default and for my project then hit ok and reformatted the code but still code exceeds the Right margin line.

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?